# How to map two tables to one entity using foreign-key?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem very similar to this: [How do I join tables on non-primary key columns in secondary tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1494368/1061499)
But I'm not sure if I can apply the same solution.

I have two tables like these:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
    CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DETAIL_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( CUSTOMER_ID ),
    CONSTRAINT cust_fk FOREIGN KEY( DETAIL_ID ) REFERENCES DETAILS( DETAIL_ID )
)

CREATE TABLE DETAILS
(
    DETAIL_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    OTHER INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( DETAIL_ID )
)
```

I'd like to map these tables to a single class called `Customer`, so I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMERS")
@SecondaryTable(name = "DETAILS", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="DETAIL_ID"))
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Integer id;

   @Column(table = "DETAILS", name = "OTHER")
   private Integer notes;

   // ...
}
```

but this works only if `DETAIL_ID` matches `CUSTOMER_ID` in the primary table.

So my question is: how can i use a foreign-key field in my primary table to join on the primary-key of the secondary table?

---

**UPDATE**
I tried to set:

`@SecondaryTable(name = "DETAILS", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="DETAIL_ID", referencedColumnName="DETAIL_ID"))`

but when I run the application I get this exception:

`org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: DETAIL_ID in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(CUSTOMERS) and its related supertables and secondary tables`

Comment: OK, so you have two tables, and you want to join them in a single table?

Comment: @SerenityStackHolder Yes, I want to map two tables on a single Entity. But I have a foreign key in the primary table to the secondary table.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for an answer to this, using @SecondaryTable is not the way to join two tables with non-primary key columns, because Hibernate will try to assosiate the two tables by their primary keys by default; you have to use @OneToMany review http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/ for a solution, here's a code snippet in case that url stops working:

Customer Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMERS")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DETAIL_ID")
    private Details details;

    // Getter and Setter methods...
}
```

Details Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DETAILS")
public class Details {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="DETAIL_ID")
    private int detailId;

    @Column(name="OTHER")
    private String other;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="details")
    private Set<Customer> customers;

    // Getter and Setter methods...
}
```

This is easily accessible through hibernate with the following code:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Query query = session.createQuery("select id, details.other from Customer");
```

I hope this helps anyone out there spending hours searching for a way to achieve this like I did.

Comment: this doesn't map the two tables into a single entity as the OP wanted, this is the usual bidirectional One-To-Many mapping

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `referenceColumnName` attribute of the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation to define the join column to the referenced table. In fact, by combining use of name/referencedColumnName you can join on arbitrary on both sides, with the constraint that if duplicates are found your ORM provider will throw an exception.